# Clang-format style rules for parentheses and access modifier

Tags: clang-format

I trying to write my own clang-format style file. There are two aspects I cannot get them right.

How do I let it keep an empty line after `public:`, `private:`, `protected:`? For example, I would like to have

```
public :

ctor () {}
```

Instead of

```
public :
ctor () {}
```

The second issues is that is there a way to make it insert a space before parentheses when it is following and control statement *and* function definition. But no space before a function call. For example, I would want,

```
void func () {}
func()
```

The `SpaceBeforeParens` can be only one of `Never`, `Always`, `ControlStatements`. The last is closest to what I want, yet it still does not work the way I want. A minor related issue is that it always remove space before the parenthesis if it follows an unary operator, for example

```
C &operator=(const C &);
```

I am more used to

```
C &operator= (const C &);
```

Comment: I'm also looking for a way to add a line break before/after access modifiers!

Comment: Same here. I would love to know a way to add a line after access modifiers.

Comment: Five years later, these still don't seem to be supported by clang-format.

Comment: There seems to be a new option `EmptyLineAfterAccessModifier` which adresses the first problem. It can be found here: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html. But even though the documentation has the heading "Clang 12 documentation", the `clang-format` shipped with Clang 12 outputs "error: unknown key 'EmptyLineAfterAccessModifier'" here... :-(

Comment: This page https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ReleaseNotes.html#clang-format states that `EmptyLineAfterAccessModifier` has been added in Clang 13.

Comment: To make that easier we have recently added the notation when an option was added. Note that some options may have been added earlier than stated, because we did not dig too deep into the changes to said options.