# clang-format option to add newline before and after C++ / header access modifier?

Tags: clang-format

what option can I set in the .clang-format file to add a newline before and after a access modifier in C++/.h header file?

What I don't want:

```
class HixConfig {
  public:
    HixConfig();
  private:
    const char * getMQTTServer(void){return "192.168.99.219"};
};
```

What I want:

```
class HixConfig {

  public:

    HixConfig();

  private:

    const char * getMQTTServer(void){return "192.168.99.219"};

};
```

I tried the options mentioned on https://clangformat.com but could not find any that matches my required behavior.

Comment: set `MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 1`

Comment: @Kalana But that does not insert empty lines, does it? It only adjusts which empty lines to remove...?!

Comment: This question is similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29736248/clang-format-style-rules-for-parentheses-and-access-modifier.

Comment: I think this is a bug report requesting this feature: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/38042

Answer (score 0):

For any one looking for an answer ...
add to .clang-format file the following two lines:

`EmptyLineBeforeAccessModifier: Always`

`EmptyLineAfterAccessModifier: Always`